# How useful macroeconomic indicators at item-level forecasting?

Tags: forecasting

When planning forecasting strategies for an organization with high hierarchy (at geography, market product level), can I conclude that:

For the medium (~3 months-2 years) and long horizon (~2 years and up) forecasts macroeconomic indicators are crucial to achieve better forecasts.
But, at the item-level  forecasts for purchasing and inventory planning, since they have short horizons (~0-3 months), macroeconomic  indicators (external variables) has the minimum effect, instead  the  internal variables such as price changes and promotions must be considered perhaps in a multiple linear regression.

I am new to inventory forecasting and, eager to know your thoughts. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends enormously on your situation.

The first question is what an "item" is. This may be a stock keeping unit (SKU). Or not. For instance, in fashion, a "product" is typically a specific cut of a garment, which is then split up to colors and sizes, so the color-size combination defines the SKU, and one "product" may have twenty or more SKUs. Of course, the more aggregate the time series you forecast is, the easier it will be to extract signals. If your "item" is a barrel of crude oil (of which there are again multiple different variants), then macro conditions may indeed be relevant for forecasting.

The "other" dimensions are also relevant, e.g., the location dimension (are you forecasting for a single distribution center or supermarket, or for an entire country), and the temporal aggregation: forecasts on monthly or quarterly level have much more signal and less noise than forecasts on daily level - so again, the more you aggregate, the more easily you will be able to extract signals and leverage drivers.

However, if your "item" is a SKU that is sold at retail, and you need forecasts on day/store level, macro data is utterly useless. As is, often, weather or substitution effects. On this level, promotions and prices are *far* more important. (It is relevant that prices and promotions actually happen on precisely this granularity, not on the more aggregate levels per above, where and "promotion" or "price" is necessarily some aggregate.)

Of course, there is always the question of any lags in relationships between macro conditions and the time series of interest. Housing permits applied for is typically a good leading indicator for demand for lumber a few months later. In other cases, the focal time series may actually *lag behind* the macro indicator - if the business climate is *forecasted* to get worse, businesses may already elect to reduce their expenses *today*.

You may find [Syntetos et al. (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2015.11.010) helpful, especially the figure visualizing the different hierarchies involved.